# Chrome renders page twice while Safari works as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

Ruby on Rails 6.0 (RC1) renders with Bootstrap 4.3.1 correctly on Safari but seems to render the page on Chrome twice (so it appears), first without using the Bootstrap CSS information, then applies the Bootstrap formatting. For a fraction of a second I can see the page in it's "raw" format before it gets reformatted.

Chrome on Windows: same result, renders twice / flickers
Edge: works correctly
Firefox on Windows: misbehaves like Chrome does

With working correctly I mean it does not flicker when rendering the page.

Here is what I did.

1. Create a new RoR application

```
  rails new test600
```

2. Create a controller

```
  cd test600
  rails g controller main index
```

3. Install Bootstrap, JQuery and Popper

```
  yarn add bootstrap@4.3.1 jquery popper.js
```

4. Edit config/webpack/environment.js so it reads:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

5. Edit app/javascript/packs/application.js and add

```
require('jquery')
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
```

6. Edit app/views/layouts/application.html to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test600WithBootstrap</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
      <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">Company name</h5>
      <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
        <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </nav>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Sign up</a>
    </div>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

7. Start the application, either rails s or puma, both give the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue known as [Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). This might be due to your `require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')` in application.js, which downloads the CSS file asynchronously while the page is loading, instead of blocking the page load while the style sheet is downloaded, and its styles are applied.

Comment: Thanks, that is the problem. Now I need to figure out how solve it as I have no means of knowing in which sequence the CSS files are loaded.

Comment: Just include bootstrap.css normally with a `<link>` tag or using the `@import` directive in another style sheet.

Comment: I think there should be any better solution, @GregBurghardt. Because that way we need to kind of throw webpack away and get back to asset pipeline.

Comment: @DiegoStiehl: This is really a browser issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In compliment to [Greg Burghardt's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060032/1148768) and to help people who will land here I want to add two tips that helped me.

1. Verify if you are using `stylesheet_pack_tag` instead of (or next to) `stylesheet_link_tag` inside your `application.html.erb`.
2. Set `extract_css: true` at `config/webpacker.yml` ([source](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1542#issuecomment-470678178)).

Answer (score 1):

#### What **didn't** work:

Doing it this way had the flash of unstyled content.

```js
// app/javascript/styles/application.js
import("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap");
```

#### What **did** work:

```js
// app/javascript/styles/application.js
import 'styles/site'
```

```
// app/javascript/styles/site.scss
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";
```

in config/webpacker.yml

```
 extract_css: true
```

#### Reference

This took a little trial and error.

- [@DiegoStiehl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314285/5783745) was helpful
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162932/5783745) answer to a related problem says to create at least one css file and import it, so I tried that (the bootstrap file, but presumably you could use any)
- [This](https://rossta.net/blog/webpacker-with-bootstrap.html) article showed me how to do that