# ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

i've tried many suggestions and answers from all around the web and something is just missing.
I keep getting the above error while trying to open my app (which works perfectly locally) on Heroku.
I've followed the standard instructions for deploying an app using git and heroku cli.
I have pushed everything to heroku but while trying to visit my site via the html i keep getting "We're sorry, but something went wrong." and the console shows this error:

```
2020-09-22T12:29:49.151911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=thawing-retreat-03527.herokuapp.com request_id=eac8d868-4c14-4c1d-be40-0741778518c7 fwd="83.130.59.73" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2020-09-22T12:29:49.410973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thawing-retreat-03527.herokuapp.com request_id=3b73846f-7d13-4159-b33b-be26db60b209 fwd="83.130.59.73" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2020-09-22T12:53:00.330777+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-09-22T12:53:00.330645 #4]  INFO -- : [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291] Started GET "/" for 83.130.59.73 at 2020-09-22 12:53:00 +0000
2020-09-22T12:53:00.332093+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-09-22T12:53:00.332025 #4]  INFO -- : [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291] Processing by PagesController#about as HTML
2020-09-22T12:53:00.334335+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-09-22T12:53:00.334265 #4]  INFO -- : [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]   Rendering pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application
2020-09-22T12:53:00.335195+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-09-22T12:53:00.335130 #4]  INFO -- : [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]   Rendered pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 141)
2020-09-22T12:53:00.336616+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-09-22T12:53:00.336554 #4]  INFO -- : [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (Allocations: 839)
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338353+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-09-22T12:53:00.338286 #4] FATAL -- : [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338354+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338357+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338357+00:00 app[web.1]: unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338358+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338359+00:00 app[web.1]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338359+00:00 app[web.1]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338360+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338361+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338362+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338362+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338363+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]      6:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338364+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]      7:
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338365+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]      8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338365+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]      9:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338366+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]     10:   </head>
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338366+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]     11:
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338367+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]     12:   <body>
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338367+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291]
2020-09-22T12:53:00.338368+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d66d3df-99bc-4899-93d2-a203bddc9291] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
```

I think I made a mistake while making this app bootstrap friendly. Or maybe something is wrong with my files.. I'm truly lost at this point.

These are my files:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.3-2",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "trix": "^1.2.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

application.js:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
import 'bootstrap'
import '../stylesheets/style'
```

style.scss:

```
    @import "bootstrap";
```

webpacker.yml:

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file_
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

application.html.erb:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
import 'bootstrap'
import '../stylesheets/style'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
end

group :test, :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
 gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

#### custom gem area 
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.0.0.alpha1'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'faker'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'solargraph', group: :development
gem 'rubocop', group: :development
####


# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-0da4851a98444f0352a0.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-0da4851a98444f0352a0.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-0da4851a98444f0352a0.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-0da4851a98444f0352a0.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpacker 4.2 can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161189/webpacker-4-2-cant-find-application-in-app-public-packs-manifest-json-heroku)